# How can I use two ranged weapons against two different targets?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, combat, feats, weapons

Ok, so in our DnD 3.5 campaign we're using a custom setting with reduced magic but includes early firearms e.g. flintlocks, revolvers, muskets, Dwarven Hand Cannon (prototype shotgun). My character has Two-Weapon Fighting and has a pair of revolvers (with attached blades) in his arsenal. As far as I can tell I can only use two weapons against the same target in one attack using Two-Weapon Fighting; what sort of feats would I need to use each one against a different target in one round? (for rules purposes, we're more or less treating firearms with the same rules as crossbows/hand crossbows/repeaters).

Comment: As a side note, you probably don't need all those tags... just D&D 3.5e would be just fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no rule stating that all attacks made during a Full Attack action need to be against a single target. This is true regardless of why you are making multiple attacks. In fact, as long as you declare you are making a full attack action, you can switch targets after ever attack, based on if it hit or not, etc.

This is backed up by the rules for [Full Attack actions](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#fullAttack) which states:

> If you get more than one attack per round [...] because you fight with two weapons [...] **You do not need to specify the *targets* of your attacks ahead of time.** You can see how the earlier attacks turn out before assigning the later ones.

Note that this is only applicable to Full Attack actions. Any *other* action allowing multiple attacks, (such as maneuvers or feats like Cleave,) will impose their own restrictions on if you can or cannot switch targets.

Comment: Ah, ok then. So going "gun kata" on everyone is theoretically fine as long as it's a full attack?

Still would be nice to hit two targets once with a standard attack.

Comment: @Cobalt Unfortunately, multiple attacks on a standard action are rare, and the usual option for ranged characters to do so ([Manyshot](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#manyshot)) is one of the things that requires you to attack the same target it with both attacks.

Comment: @KRyan I know there is Improved Manyshot, which *does* let you fire each shot at a different target, but it has a rather long feat progression and it's exclusive to bows; I don't think it would work very well with revolvers.

Comment: @Cobalt if you want to hit two targets with a standard action firearm attack in a non-high-tech setting use a shotgun.